# How can I link a to a second view controller using a button determined by a variable?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have created a UIPickerView which has an array of services inside. I have used the didSelectRow to display my selected service below the UIPickerView. That's all fine and works perfectly.

I want the service which as been selected to take me to another view controller named that service. For example, Coffee shops as been selected in the Picker, "coffee shops" is displayed below the picker and you click a button which will bring you to a page which displays the given information about coffee shops.

@Pbush25 thanks for the quick reply. Please would you take a look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong as I still can't get it to work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var SelectedService: UILabel!
    @IBAction func Find(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ItemLabel: UILabel!

    var services = ["Cafe","Coffee Shops","Bar","Takeaway","Sunday Roast","Shoe Mender","Craft Shops","Electrical"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{

        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return services.count   
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
        return services[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIPickerView` objects contain a `selectedRowInComponent` function which returns the row number of the selected row.  Based on that number, you should be able to write a function that pushes a new view controller based on the selected value.

Answer (score 2):

As @JAL said, there is a method for the `UIPickerViewDelegate` that I belive is `didSelectRow` or something to that extent, which will give you the index path of the row that was selected. When your button is pressed to go to the next screen, all you have to do in your `prepareForSegue` method is get the element at that row and use a switch statement to determine which new view controller to activate the segue on based on what value you receive.

EDIT: Added code for clarity.

```
//save the picked data to a variable
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    selection = "\(pickerViewData[row])"
}

//use this variable to decide which segue to take
func prepareForSegue(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    switch selection {
    case: "Coffee Shops" 
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToCoffeeShops", sender: self)

    case: "Some other selection"
        performSegueWithIdentifier("someOtherSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast reply. It doesn't want to work. I have been playing around with the code for a while now and I cant get it to work. I'm quite new to swift so i have put my code below - maybe you could tell me where I am going wrong.